# How to get previous two years max value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Hi I have data frame as

How to create column max_value with max from last 2 years max value

```
dt <- 
structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L
), value = c(22L, 99L, 12L, 1L, 23L, 40L, 12L, 12L, 33L, 40L, 
NA, 20L, 20L), max_value = c(NA, NA, 99L, 99L, 12L, 23L, 40L, 
NA, 12L, 12L, 40L, 40L, 20L)), .Names = c("Name", "year", "value", 
"max_value"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

Name   year   value   *max_value*
A      2012    22        NA
A      2012    99        NA
A      2013    12        99
A      2014    01        99
A      2015    23        12
A      2016    40        23
A      2017    12        40
B      2012    12        NA
B      2013    33        12
B      2013    40        12
B      2014    NA        40
B      2015    20        40
B      2016    20        20
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Grouped by Name? Is that why max value in row "B 2012" is NA? And why two NAs at the start of A's data and only one at the start of Bs? Oh multiple years in year.... Its not just a rollapply...

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: @akrun the expected output is in the `*max_value*` column.

Comment: Yes grouped by Name ,two NAs are showing at 2012 because it dont have the previous year(above 2012) for both A and B group in Name column

Comment: You can use `roll_max` from `RcppRoll`.  Try `library(RcppRoll);library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, roll_max(value, 2, fill=NA, align = "right"), Name]`

Comment: Yes akrun spacedman is correct

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other data.table approach, using a self-join by `.EACHI`

```
library(data.table)
# temporary rowwise id
setDT(dt)[, id := .I]
# set key
setkey(dt, id)
# self join, set infinite values back to NA
dt[dt, max_val2 := {
  dt[Name == i.Name & year >= (i.year - 2) & year < i.year, max(value, na.rm = TRUE)]
}, by = .EACHI][is.infinite(max_val2), max_val2 := NA][, id := NULL]

    Name year value max_value max_val2
 1:    A 2012    22        NA       NA
 2:    A 2012    99        NA       NA
 3:    A 2013    12        99       99
 4:    A 2014     1        99       99
 5:    A 2015    23        12       12
 6:    A 2016    40        23       23
 7:    A 2017    12        40       40
 8:    B 2012    12        NA       NA
 9:    B 2013    33        12       12
10:    B 2013    40        12       12
11:    B 2014    NA        40       40
12:    B 2015    20        40       NA
13:    B 2016    20        20       NA
```

Answer (score 2):

The complication here is that the years have different numbers of entries. This can be worked around by grouping, then summarizing to get a within-year maximum. Next use `slide_int()` to get the max of the two prior years, to ultimately join this yearly data back to the original frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

sol <- dt %>%
  group_by(Name, year) %>%
  summarize(max_val = max(value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(slide_max = slide_int(lag(max_val), max, 
                               .before = 1, na.rm = TRUE, .complete = T)) %>%
  select(-max_val) %>%
  right_join(dt, by = c("Name", "year"))

sol
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#> # Groups:   Name [2]
#>    Name   year slide_max value max_value
#>    <chr> <int>     <int> <int>     <int>
#>  1 A      2012        NA    22        NA
#>  2 A      2012        NA    99        NA
#>  3 A      2013        99    12        99
#>  4 A      2014        99     1        99
#>  5 A      2015        12    23        12
#>  6 A      2016        23    40        23
#>  7 A      2017        40    12        40
#>  8 B      2012        NA    12        NA
#>  9 B      2013        12    33        12
#> 10 B      2013        12    40        12
#> 11 B      2014        40    NA        40
#> 12 B      2015        40    20        40
#> 13 B      2016        20    20        20

identical(sol$slide_max, sol$max_value)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What a beautiful and complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method with data.table using aggregation, a two dimensional `shift`, `apply`, and a join.

```
library(data.table)
dt[dt[, .(mx=max(value)), by=c("Name", "year")
      ][, .(year,
            max_val=apply(matrix(unlist(shift(mx, 1:2)), ncol=2), 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)),
        by=Name],
    on=c("Name", "year")][is.infinite(max_val), max_val := NA][]
```

The first line calculates the maximum value by year and name. The second line, for each name, the year and using `apply` the maximum of the two lagged years (using `shift(mx, 1:2)`) are returned, dropping NA values. This results in warnings for every line that has 2 NA values, and a -Inf is returned in that place. I had to manually convert the output of `shift` into a matrix, in order to feed it to apply, which is not ideal. The resulting data.table is joined onto the original using name and year as IDs. Finally, the -Inf values are replaced with NA in the final line and the result printed with `[]`.

This returns

```
    Name year value max_value max_val
 1:    A 2012    22        NA      NA
 2:    A 2012    99        NA      NA
 3:    A 2013    12        99      99
 4:    A 2014     1        99      99
 5:    A 2015    23        12      12
 6:    A 2016    40        23      23
 7:    A 2017    12        40      40
 8:    B 2012    12        NA      NA
 9:    B 2013    33        12      12
10:    B 2013    40        12      12
11:    B 2014    NA        40      40
12:    B 2015    20        40      40
13:    B 2016    20        20      20
```

**data**

```
dt <- 
structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L
), value = c(22L, 99L, 12L, 1L, 23L, 40L, 12L, 12L, 33L, 40L, 
NA, 20L, 20L), max_value = c(NA, NA, 99L, 99L, 12L, 23L, 40L, 
NA, 12L, 12L, 40L, 40L, 20L)), .Names = c("Name", "year", "value", 
"max_value"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got so far. The [slider package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/slider-0-1-0/) is par of the tidyverse,

```
library(slider)
dt %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
       mutate(slide_max = slide_dbl(lag(value), max, .before = 2, na.rm = TRUE, .complete = T))
# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   Name [2]
   Name   year value max_value slide_max
   <chr> <int> <int>     <int>     <dbl>
 1 A      2012    22        NA        NA
 2 A      2012    99        NA        NA
 3 A      2013    12        99        99
 4 A      2014     1        99        99
 5 A      2015    23        12        99
 6 A      2016    40        23        23
 7 A      2017    12        40        40
 8 B      2012    12        NA        NA
 9 B      2013    33        12        NA
10 B      2013    40        12        33
11 B      2014    NA        40        40
12 B      2015    20        40        40
13 B      2016    20        20        40
```

Comment: The issue in your approach is that you are trying to use `slide_dbl()`, which works based on position, on data that has a varying number of observations per year. I have posted an answer that addresses this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using mapply.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                 year = c(2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
                 value = c(22, 99, 12, 1, 23, 40, 12, 12, 33, 40, NA, 20, 20),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

max.vals <- mapply(function(x, y){
                     vals <- df[df$year %in% c(x-2,x-1) & df$Name == y,"value"]
                     max.val <- ifelse(length(vals) > 0, max(vals, na.rm = TRUE), NA)
                     max.val <- list(y,x,max.val)
                     names(max.val) <- c("Name","year","max_value")
                     return(max.val)
                   },
                  unique(df[,c("Name","year")])$year,
                  unique(df[,c("Name","year")])$Name
                 ) 

max.vals <- as.data.frame(t(max.vals),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- merge(df, max.vals)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `by`:

```
> by(dat$value, dat$year, function(x) max(x))
dat$year: 2012
[1] 99
------------------------------------------------------------ 
dat$year: 2013
[1] 40
------------------------------------------------------------ 
dat$year: 2014
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------ 
dat$year: 2015
[1] 23
------------------------------------------------------------ 
dat$year: 2016
[1] 40
------------------------------------------------------------ 
dat$year: 2017
[1] 12
```

EDIT: Misunderstood the question at first. This should be what you want:

Assign the results to a data.frame:

```
> dat1=by(dat$value, dat$year, function(x) max(x))
> data.frame("max"=dat1[1:length(dat1)])
     max
2012  99
2013  40
2014  NA
2015  23
2016  40
2017  12
```

Make a new data frame to hold biannual maximum and loop to compare years:

```
bi_max=data.frame("max"=nrow(dat_max))
for(i in 1:nrow(dat_max)){
  bi_max[i,]=max(dat_max$max[i], dat_max$max[i-1], na.rm=T)
}
rownames(bi_max)=rownames(dat_max)
```

The final result:

```
> bi_max
     max
2012  99
2013  99
2014  40
2015  23
2016  40
2017  40
```

Comment: Oops! Should be fixed now.

Comment: That's better, but compare your results with the desired results on the OP. They also want the two year maxes separately for each name. (not my downvote btw).